# java convert in UTF-8 character (è) problem

Tags: java, json

Hi I have a problem with java ... the json arrives in an array of strings correctly but the characters (is) are A ... can someone help me with the conversion to UTF-8 and to string

Thanks

```
private static void loadProperties() throws Exception {
        String properties = null;
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(getEndpoint()).openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer res = new StringBuffer();
        while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            res.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(res.toString()).getAsJsonObject();
        if(jsonObject.has("error")) {
            JsonObject error = jsonObject.get("error").getAsJsonObject();
            if(error.has("errorCode") && "1000".equals(error.get("errorCode").getAsString()) && jsonObject.has("data")) {
                properties = jsonObject.get("data").getAsJsonArray().toString();
                log("PropertiesUtils.loadProperties: Properties = %s", properties);
                setProperties(properties);
            } else {
                throw new Exception("PropertiesUtils.loadProperties: Error while calling properties endpoint");
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception("PropertiesUtils.loadProperties: Error while calling properties endpoint");     
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that you need not do the whole read-into-string loop you built: you can directly call [`JSONParser.parse()`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html#parse-java.io.Reader-) with the `BufferedReader in` as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here:

```
new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream())
```

This takes the `InputStream` streaming the HTTP response (i.e. a pure byte stream) and re-interprets it as text using the default encoding (because you didn't specify one).

The default encoding depends entirely on *your computer, OS and settings* and is entirely unrelated to the encoding that the remote server might be sending you data.

You need to use [`con.getContentEncoding()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentEncoding--) to get the encoding that the server informs you about:

```
new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), con.getContentEncoding());
```

Comment: con.getContentEncoding() i try with this ...but ide give me an error

Comment: @emaAme: how did you try that and *what* error does it give you? Don't just treat error messages as red flags. *Read them*.